# SweetAlert 2 button cancel submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

2nd alert shows even I click cancel button on first alert. I want the alert close if i click the cancel button

```
$('#tblUser tbody').on('click','.reset',function(){ 
       Swal.fire({
          title: 'Reset password?',
          text: "",
          icon: 'question',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
       }).then(() => {
         Swal.fire(
             'Reset!',
             'Your password has been reset.',
             'success'
       ).then((result)=>{
            if(result.value){
                 $(this).closest('form').submit();
            } 
       });
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether user input yes or cancel so need to check flag condition here ..

```
$('#tblUser tbody').on('click','.reset',function(){ 
       Swal.fire({
          title: 'Reset password?',
          text: "",
          icon: 'question',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
       }).then((result) => {
          if(result.value) {
               Swal.fire(
                  'Reset!',
                  'Your password has been reset.',
                  'success'
               ).then((result)=>{
                   if(result.value){
                      $(this).closest('form').submit();
                   } 
               });
           }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I got error on your code sir my data on datatable not showing but thanks for the response, and i solve it already

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tblUser tbody').on('click','.reset',function(){ 
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Reset password?',
  text: "",
  icon: 'question',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
}).then((result) => {
if(result.value){
Swal.fire(
  'Reset!',
  'Your password has been reset.',
  'success'
).then(()=>{
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
} })});
});
```